# Java: Is Stack.addAll the same as pushing elements individually?

Tags: java, stack

If I want to add a number of elements at once, regardless of their order (for DFS), does Java's generic addAll() method for Stack work the same way as the Stack-specific push(), just with a number of elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, Stack's implementation defined by Vector.addAll, which looks like this:

```
/**
 * Appends all of the elements in the specified Collection to the end of
 * this Vector, in the order that they are returned by the specified
 * Collection's Iterator.  The behavior of this operation is undefined if
 * the specified Collection is modified while the operation is in progress.
 * (This implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if the
 * specified Collection is this Vector, and this Vector is nonempty.)
 */
public synchronized boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    modCount++;
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
    ensureCapacityHelper(elementCount + numNew);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, elementCount, numNew);
    elementCount += numNew;
    return numNew != 0;
}
```

So it doesn't just call push in a loop.

We can compare this with the `Vector.addElement` function which `Stack.push` calls:

```
public synchronized void addElement(E obj) {
    modCount++;
    ensureCapacityHelper(elementCount + 1);
    elementData[elementCount++] = obj;
}
```

If you called push in a loop, there would be at least unneeded multiple calls to `ensureCapacityHelper`. Therefore, as you might expect, *I suspect* `addAll` has better performance.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Functionally, they achieve the same goal, but not necessarily in the same way.

Long answer: From the documentation of [`Stack#push`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push(E)):

> Pushes an item onto the top of this stack. This has exactly the same effect as:
>    `addElement(item)`

Further, [`Vector#addElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addElement(E)) says:

> Adds the specified component to the end of this vector

So therefore, `push` appends to the end of the `Vector`.

Now, from the documentation of [`Vector#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)):

> Appends all of the elements in the specified Collection to the end of this Vector, in the order that they are returned by the specified Collection's Iterator.

This has the same effect of calling `addElement` on each element, and thus (by extension) the same effect of calling `push` on each element.

That said, `addAll` will likely do things far more efficiently.